# Loop through XML nodes and update each nodes with value from database C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, linq-to-xml, facebook-c#-sdk

I have a XML file like this: I'm creating event node for the number of records i have in the database.

```
<event_list>
<event>
 <servername></servername>
</event>
<event>
<servername></servername>
</event>
<event>
<servername></servername>
</event>
<event>
<title></title>
</event>
</event_list>
```

I will get value of servers from database. I'm not able to pass each server name to corresponding node. Instead i'm ending up updating all four nodes with last server name with following function:

```
public static XmlDocument OpenXmlFile(string fileLocation,     List<ServiceObjects> Sqldata)
{

 eventlist_location = @"C:\Temp\List.xml";

 XMLFileManagement FM = new XMLFileManagement();

FM.CreateXML(eventlist_location);

XmlDocument template = new XmlDocument();

template.Load(fileLocation);

XmlDocument Neweventlist = new XmlDocument();

for (var item in Sqldata)

{

 XmlNamespaceManager namespaces = new     XmlNamespaceManager(template.NameTable);

namespaces.AddNamespace("n", "http://www.hp.com/2009");

XmlNode node = template.SelectSingleNode(".//n:event", namespaces);

Neweventlist.Load(eventlist_location);

     Neweventlist.DocumentElement.AppendChild(Neweventlist.ImportNode(template.DocumentElement, true));

 XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(Neweventlist.NameTable);

namespaces.AddNamespace("abc", "http://www.hp.com/2009");

 foreach (XmlNode Xnode in Neweventlist.SelectNodes(".//*", namespaces))

{

if (Xnode.Name == "servername")

Xnode.InnerText = item.ServerName.ToString();



}
Neweventlist.Save(eventlist_location);

}

return Neweventlist;

}
```

Comment: So what is the question/problem?

Comment: @RasmusDamgaardNielsen I'm not able to pass each server name to corresponding node. Instead i'm ending up updating all four nodes with last server name in the DB table. I want to update each node with server names i receive from the table